# How is Laravel decoding HTTP request body Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded when using api call

Tags: laravel, api, http-headers, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel-5.5 and i'm developing an apis for an iOS app.

Here, i'm using postman to call all apis. I've one registration api with two headers:

1) `Authorization: Bearer access_token`

2) `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Now when i requesting this api i just want to print `dd($request->all());` But it's not give me proper request data. I've tried `json_decode(urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input')));` to decode it and also tried `$request->getContent();` but no luck!

Can anyone knows how to get request data in controller when using `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`??

**EDIT:**

```
public function registration(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->all());
     dd($request->getContent());  //also tried but not work 
     dd(json_decode(urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'))));   //no luck
}
```

Comment: Share code of request and where you put request->all() ?

Comment: @C2486: I've just put `$request->all();` in first line of my function! And pass the param in postman.

Comment: Please share those code ?

Comment: @C2486: I've updated it! Do you want to see anything else?

Comment: have you added CORS for api ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry: No, i've not added CORS.

Comment: then add and try it , see : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors ,  https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1

Comment: @SaurabhMistry: Ok, i'll try! But any other way/solution to handle this?

Comment: @C2486: Do you want any other code?

Comment: @HirenGohel , have you found any solution ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry: I've posted my answer! Please check it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it like this:

```
$requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
dd($requestData);
```

Pass headers `Content-Type: application/json` in postman and it's fixed!!

You only need to do this:

```
$requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

and you can get all request data in your controller in your request!

Hope this will helps to any users in future!!